# Cannot consistently disable Visual Studio 2019 warnings for headers with #pragma or project warning level

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, warnings, pragma

I am using SDL2/GLAD and [stb_image.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb) with OpenGL, but AFAIK my problem is independent of that fact. I am editing properties under all configuration and I am not using precompiled headers.

I want to up my warning level to /W4 or even /Wall. However, /Wall gives me up to 1273 errors, most from the math library `glm`. So, I wrapped my external includes in a `#pragma` push/pop directive, but it seems to do absolutely nothing. Specifically disabling warnings with `#pragma warning(disable : n)` does nothing either.

When I started writing this question, no matter how or where I placed my #pragma directives (around headers, within headers, around functions, around calls), or whether I had my project warning level set anywhere from /W0 to /W4, about 80 errors would sneak through: one from SDL2, and the rest from `stb_image.h`. However, randomly during testing, my error list can jump between ~7 errors from `stb_image.h` back up to 70+.

I'm struggling to find any consistency in how Visual Studio handles errors. I just want to turn off errors from external headers and libraries so I can only see errors from code I have written. What am I doing wrong?

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <SDL.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image/stb_image.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#pragma warning(pop)

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

// ...

Image LoadTexture(const std::string& path, GLenum format) {
    int width, height, channels;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(path.c_str(), &width, &height, &channels, STBI_default);

    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    if (data) {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load texture " << path << std::endl;
        texture = -1; // error
    }

    stbi_image_free(data);
    return { texture, width, height, channels };
}

// ...
```

Comment: This should work. For consistency ensure you're always testing the exact same build. Clean first, then build or rebuild. I assume you are not using precompiled headers based on the example. If you are you should note that in the question.

Comment: I am not using precompiled headers and I will add that to the post. I am cleaning and rebuilding to refresh the error list, and near the end as I got more frustrated I was relaunching VS too.

Comment: You might want to check the headers of the library you're using (glm, etc) and see if they have things that are affected by macros that (say) have been defined in some of your source files but not in others.    It's not exactly unusual for library authors to have conditional debugging or checking code that tweaks warnings from compilers differently based on what macros are defined (e.g. that use `#pragma push` or `pop` with Visual studio - which could interact with your usage of such pragmas).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of IntelliSense, it seems to ignore "#pragma warning(push, 0)"

IntelliSense is very unstable (and we are in year 2022 already!)

What solved the problem for me is to select "Build Only" in the listbox, as the print bellow:

[image: Error list - Build Only]